# Stuck on remote debugging. Not being able to open URL to mobile browser

Tags: remote-debugging, chromecast, chrome-remote-debugging

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the [remote debugging documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) of chrome devtools. But the devtools are displaying chromecast as connected device and do not show any interface to open URL in mobile browser. I have tried it on both Chrome and Chrome Canary. Also my device is Galaxy Tab A.

[image: devtools screenshot]

I can provide more information if required.

Comment: Please provide more information...

Comment: Here are this list of steps I have followed:
1- Enabled USB Debugging in device.
2- Connected the Galaxy Tab A with my computer while both screens are unlocked and developer tool is focused.
3- I have verified the device drivers, they are up to date.

PS: I am connecting it with windows 7 machine.